# How to get rid of zeros in the result-set of a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a join statement that is finding the ratio of cost to charge.  The query is right, but returning the 5 zeroes after the decimal place.  I tried the round function but it did not work.

The Query:

```
Select Book, Year, (Round(Sum(Cost/Fee),2) As 'Ratio'
From Book B
Inner Join Fees F
On B.Fee_Code = F.Fee_Code
Group By Book, Year;
```

It is returning 15.250000000 for the Ratio

- 15.25 is correct, I just want to knock off the zeroes

Comment: There isn't enough information here to provide a correct answer without guessing. For example, if the second row is 13.666666666 or 14.275, what result do you want? In other words, are you intending to round to 2 decimal places, or are you intending to truncate at the first zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to CAST the result as a decimal with only 2 places

e.g.

```
CAST(Sum(Cost/Fee) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) As 'Ratio'
```

Comment: Note that syntax using single quotes to quote identifiers does not have a very promising future. `'foo' = 1` is already deprecated. `[square brackets]` are usually preferred.

Comment: Interesting that everyone on the page chose the same precision and scale. :-)

Comment: @Aaron `hive-mind` :) Noted re the single-quotes. I guess I should also *always* semicolon-terminate all my SQL code on this site now?

Comment: @Richard yes, I would recommend that too. When possible, your code should always be future-proof. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I can see one more parenthesis before the Round function, but anyway try this:
`CAST(Sum(Cost/Fee) AS DECIMAL(10,2))`